# How can I use weblate in my android project

Tags: android, internationalization, weblate

I want to translate string.xml of my android project into different languages. How can I use [weblate](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite some options:

- [Install Weblate on your server](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/quick.html)
- [Use Docker container for Weblate](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/deployments.html)
- [Ask for free hosting if you are developing free software](https://weblate.org/hosting/#free)
- [Buy commercial hosting](https://weblate.org/hosting/)